# JSON Stringify a sublist

Tags: javascript, json, node.js

This may be a noob question, but if I wanted to make a JSON list of items (in a nodejs app) I can do the following:

```
var myVar = {
  'title' : 'My Title',
  'author' : 'A Great Author'
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myVar));

OUTPUT: { 'title' : 'My Title', 'author' : 'A Great Author' }
```

and everything works great, but how do I make a sublist like the following?

```
OUTPUT: { book {'title' : 'My Title', 'author' : 'A Great Author'} }
```

Comment: Thank you, all of your answers were very helpful lol

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`{}` is the object literal syntax, `propertyName: propertyValue` defines a property. Go ahead and nest them.

```
var myVar = {
    book: {
        'title' : 'My Title',
        'author' : 'A Great Author'
    }
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To do it with JavaScript:

```
var mVar = {
  'title'  : 'My Title',
  'author' : 'A Great Author'
};

var myVar = {};

myVar.book = mVar;

console.log(JSON.stringify(myVar));​
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/JvFQJ/

To do it using the object literal notation:

```
var myVar = {
  'book': {
      'title'  : 'My Title',
      'author' : 'A Great Author'
  }
};

console.log(JSON.stringify(myVar));​
```

Answer (score 0):

As so:

```
var myVar = {
  'book': {
      'title' : 'My Title',
      'author' : 'A Great Author'
  }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd do something like this:

```
myVar = {
    book: {
        'title' : 'My Title',
        'author' : 'A Great Author'
    }
}

console.log(JSON.stringify(myVar)); // OUTPUT: { book {'title' : 'My Title', 'author' : 'A Great Author'} }
```

If you wanted multiple items in the sublist, you'd change it to this:

```
myVar = {
    book1: {
        'title' : 'My Title',
        'author' : 'A Great Author'
    },
    book2: {
        'title' : 'My Title',
        'author' : 'A Great Author'
    }
}
```